# Identical names for methods and properties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties

The following code compiles just fine - but are there any issues with it?
I couldn't find any guidelines for Objective-C that would discourage us from using the same identifier for both, properties and method names:

```
@interface MouseCursorHelper : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSCursor* rotateCursor;

+ (NSCursor*) rotateCursor;

@end
```

FWIW, the class is implemented as a singleton modeled after `NSCursor` to offer app specific cursors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be a little confusing.

The property generates 2 *instance* methods for you:

```
- (NSCursor *)rotateCursor;
- (void)setRotateCursor:(NSCursor *)rotateCursor;
```

And you also have a *class* method:

```
+ (NSCursor *)rotateCursor;
```

It isn't clear from a user point of view what the class method does. Documentation would help.

Comment: Uh, right. Obj-C doesn't have an issue with identically named instance and class methods?  The property is actually defined in the implementation file but lacking proper visibility support in Obj-C it's still accessible to the user of the class..

Comment: There is no ambiguity between class and instance methods as they are called in different ways (class object / instance). It's accessible at runtime, or via KVC, or as a method call on an `id`, but the compiler should complain in some scenarios...

Comment: Ok. I guess I can always rename the property to something silly like `rotateCursorInstance` to remove ambiguity/confusion on that level

Comment: I'd be thinking more about what you intend to achieve with the class method. Why is it not an instance method? Is your class a singleton?

Comment: Yes, it's similar to NSCursor adding more project specific cursors in the same way NSCursor offers them (via class methods a la `+ arrowCursor`. Singleton to allocate/load cursors only once.

Comment: The synthesized setter should be -setRotateCursor:, not -setCursor:

Comment: Also, 'rotateCursor' in itself is a bit confusing; sounds like a method to 'rotate the cursor'.

Comment: @ATV that sounds the same to me... Ultimately, it's up to you; but I would use e.g. "rotationCursor" (get 'rotate' out of the present tense/imperative, make the whole thing a noun)

Answer (score 2):

There's absolutely no problem with what you are doing there at all.  All you are doing is saying that both the class object and instances of the class respond to `rotateCursor`.  That's not really conceptually different to instances of NSString responding to intValue and instances of NSNumber responding to intValue.  They are just different kinds of object.

In fact, you'll find several instances of Apple doing the same thing in the Cocoa framework e.g.

```
[NSString class]; // Sending class to the class
[@"foo" class];   // Sending class to an instance of the class.
```